# Why is $G/H\to G/K$ proper and projective where $H\subseteq K\subseteq G$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a (linear) algebraic group (over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero - if you like you can assume $\mathbb{C}$). Let $K$ and $H$ be closed subgroups of $G$ such that $H\subseteq K\subseteq G$. Then we can consider the natural "projection" morphism: $\pi\colon G/H\to G/K$. I basically know that the morphism $\pi$ is separated and smooth, since the differential $d_x\pi$ is surjective at every (closed) point $x\in G/H$. Moreover since $\pi$ is smooth, we know that $\pi$ is open and closed.

My question is the following: is the morphism $\pi$ also proper and projective? This might be easy to see, but I am not sure how. Any help is appreciated. I already tried to look in books like the one of Timashev, but did not find the statement.

Note that the reasoning might not depend on the specific situation I have in mind. If you can abstract from the setup, it might be useful too. For this you may consider that $G/H$ and $G/K$ are both quasiprojective (but not necessarily projective (!)).

I am not sure, but maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771485/is-morphism-from-projective-space-projective-morphism) is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: You should tell us what situation you have in mind. If $H=\{0\}$ and $K=G$, the map is simply $G\rightarrow \{0\}$ and is not proper if $G$ isn't.

Comment: @Roland The situation is like this: I have a parabolic subgroup $P$ (actually even maximal parabolic) and another closed subgroup $Q$. Now I look at $H=P\cap Q$ and $K=Q$. Furthermore, I don't even study $\pi$ itself, I study the restriction $p$ of $\pi$ to a specific closed subvariety $X$ of $G/H$. So, I look at $p\colon X\to\pi(X)$. I know that this restriction has everywhere finite fibers and want to conclude that $p$ is a finite morphism. So I thought I must use that the morphism is proper - whence the question.